# Regular expression and csv | Output more readable

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I have a text which contains different news articles about terrorist attacks. Each article starts with an html tag (`<p>Advertisement`) and I would like to extract from each article a specific information: the number of people wounded in the terrorist attacks.

This is a sample of the text file and how the articles are separated:

```
[<p>Advertisement ,   By  MILAN SCHREUER  and     ALISSA J. RUBIN    OCT. 5, 2016 
 ,  BRUSSELS — A man wounded 2 police officers with a knife in Brussels around noon on Wednesday in what the authorities called “a potential terrorist attack.” ,  The two officers were attacked on the Boulevard Lambermont.....]
[<p>Advertisement ,,   By   KAREEM FAHIM   and    MOHAMAD FAHIM ABED   JUNE 30, 2016 
 ,  At least 33 people were killed and 25 were injured when the Taliban bombed buses carrying police cadets on the outskirts of Kabul, Afghanistan, on Thursday. ,  KABUL, Afghanistan —  Taliban  insurgents bombed a convoy of buses carrying police cadets on the outskirts of Kabul, the Afghan capital, on Thursday, killing at least 33 people, including four civilians, according to government officials and the United Nations. ,  During a year...]
```

This is my code so far:

```
text_open = open("News_cleaned_definitive.csv")
text_read = text_open.read()
splitted = text.read.split("<p>")
pattern= ("wounded (\d+)|(\d+) were wounded|(\d+) were injured")
for article in splitted:
    result = re.findall(pattern,article)
```

The output that I get is:

```
[]
[]
[]
[('', '40', '')]
[('', '150', '')]
[('94', '', '')]
```

And I would like to make the output more readable and then save it as csv file:

```
article_1,0
article_2,0
article_3,40
article_3,150
article_3,94
```

Any suggestion in how to make it more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your loop like this and merged with `csv` write since you requested it:

```
import csv

with open ("wounded.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    for i,article in enumerate(splitted):
      result = re.findall(pattern,article)
      nb_casualties = sum(int(x) for x in result[0] if x) if result else 0
      row=["article_{}".format(i+1),nb_casualties]
      writer.writerow(row)
```

- get index of the article using `enumerate`
- sum the number of victims (in case more than 1 group matches) using a generator comprehension to convert to integer and pass it to `sum`, that only if something matched (ternary expression checks that)
- create the row
- print it, or optionally write it as row (one row per iteration) of a `csv.writer` object.

Comment: It is just what I was looking for. I was wondering how I can save it properly? `with open ("wounded.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerows([row])`

Comment: you got it almost right!! let me edit that for you in my answer so it's cleaner.

Comment: Ok after one month on SO I can say you're my favourite admin.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. note: everyone can become an "admin". Just spend a lot of time answering questions properly, work your way up. I'm only 6 months old on SO.